# Fallback behavior for new iOS 13 system colors in iOS 12

Tags: ios, uikit, ios13, ios-darkmode

I’m currently adopting to Dark Mode and I figured that using the new system colors like `systemBackground` and `label` in Interface Builder also *just works* when running the app in iOS 12. I half expected to get a compiler error, but instead the app looks like in iOS 13 light mode. So obviously the runtime somehow translates those colors for iOS 12.

Does anyone know what happens under the hood and if there is a convenient way to achieve the same in code?

Comment: You can't use `UIColor.systemBackground` or `label` in iOS 12 so it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I know I can't use it in code, but I _can_ use it in storyboards which then load just fine in iOS 12. That's why I was wondering how this is working under the hood.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the XML of the storyboard, you will see something like:

```
<color key="backgroundColor" xcode11CocoaTouchSystemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
```

Xcode 11 is adding support for both colors. Whatever mechanism converts the .storyboard file into actions at runtime has the information it needs to know which color to use for iOS 13 and which color to use for iOS 12 and earlier.

In code you need something like the following:

```
extension UIColor {
    class var mySystemBackground: UIColor {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return .systemBackground
        } else {
            return .white
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So obvious… thanks! I didn't think of checking the storyboard sources for some reason…

Comment: For those wondering, this mechanism works for most XIB files created using XCode 11, not just storyboards.

Comment: The system background color is not pure white. It is likely white with some transparency.