# Understanding SystemColors for dark mode in older iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, ios-darkmode

Edit: Based on conversations below my confusion was the fact that not all of the system color are compatible with older operating systems, in my case the label and the systemBackground colors are iOS13 only which requires the fallback.  It makes sense now.

I have an app that supports iOS11 but I want to provide Dark Mode for users with iOS13.

In Xcode 11/iOS13 you can specify system colors for Dark Mode with a fallback for older operating systems as follow...

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    view.textColor = UIColor.label
} else {
    view.textColor = UIColor.black
}
```

If I try to use the color without the fallback for older systems I get an error which... kind of makes sense, I say kind of because the documentation states that `system colors (StandarColors)` are supported in iOS `7.0+`.

The funny thing is that if I use the new system colors directly from the Attributes Inspector I don't get the error, so my question is...

1- What happens when you use the new system colors directly from the Attributes Inspector where you do not get an error when selecting them?

2- What a user with `iOS11` will see on view where `label` color was directly selected from the Attributes Inspector?

Thanks

Comment: Now your question is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57364611/fallback-behavior-for-new-ios-13-system-colors-in-ios-12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the new system colors in code (except `systemOrange`, as rmaddy pointed out correctly), you have to check for iOS 13 availability because the API isn't there before.

However, when you select such a color in Interface Builder, it will work automatically in older iOS versions. Here's what Interface Builder is inserting in your storyboard in this case:

```
<color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemOrangeColor" red="1" green="0.58431372550000005" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
```

As you can see, the fallback is added in case the `systemColor` attribute is not understood.

If you want a solution that is iOS 11 compatible that doesn't require `@available` checks every time, you could use Color Assets that you define in an asset catalog.

I also created [a helper](https://github.com/DigitalMasterpieces/SystemColorCatalog) that does exactly that.